# Why do these two statements together cause a syntax error but not when they are separate?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am curious to know what these two statements as displayed show a syntax error and cause a syntax error during runtime but run fine when run indepedently. Also adding or removing the semicolon displays a different syntax error in SSMS. Using SSMS 2014 with AventureWorks database. (Statement is for testing purposes. Don't pay attention to the values)

```
select * from Person.Address;
HumanResources.uspUpdateEmployeeHireInfo 2221,'d', '3/4/1992','3/4/1992', 3,3,1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is specific to client (SSMS). You can execute stored proc without `EXEC` when the statement is single statement in the batch.

To avoid the error use:

```
select * from Person.Address;
EXEC HumanResources.uspUpdateEmployeeHireInfo 2221,'d', '3/4/1992','3/4/1992', 3,3,1
```